# Unable to run Cypress tests on Jenkins slave node?

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

Currently I have Jenkins running on a Master (Host machine) which uses Windows 10 Pro x64 and also a Slave node which also uses Windows 10 Pro x64 (Virtual Machine).

I have also configured the following Jenkins pipeline job:

```
pipeline {
agent any

tools {nodejs "node"}

stages {
    stage('Cypress Parallel Test Suite') {

        parallel {
            stage('Test_1') {
                steps {
                    git 'https://github.com/quser/cypress-auto-framework.git'
                    bat 'npm install'
                    bat 'npm update'
                    bat 'npm run triggerAllTests-dashboard'
                }
            }
            stage('Test_2') {
                agent {
                    label "remote"
                }
                steps {
                    git 'https://github.com/quser/cypress-auto-framework.git'
                    bat 'npm install'
                    bat 'npm update'
                    bat 'npm run triggerAllTests-dashboard'
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When trigger a Job from the master node, I can see that the slave node is indicating the following message:

```
In order to run in parallel mode each machine must send identical environment parameters such as:

- specs
- osName
- osVersion
- browserName
- browserVersion (major)

This machine sent the following parameters:

{  ​"osName": "win32",  ​"osVersion": "10.0.18363",  ​"browserName": "Electron",  ​"browserVersion": "80.0.3987.158",  ​"specs": [
   ​"cypress\\integration\\examples\\aliasing.spec.js",
   ​"cypress\\integration\\examples\\assertions.spec.js",
   ​"cypress\\integration\\examples\\webdriverUni\\actions.spec.js"  ​]
}
```

Please note I have added the --parallel key to my custom node script (triggerAllTests-dashboard).

Cypress doc: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages.html#Cannot-parallelize-tests-across-environments

Any ideas?

Thanks